# PHP - Change value y,n in database

Tags: php, mysql, database, codeigniter, if-statement

I try to change this value  y and n, to input in database and get from database but got problem, please help me to solve it. here my code

```
<label>Get Sponsored <span style="color:red">*</span></label> 
<select style="width:100px;" class="form-control" name="sponsor"> 
   <?php
                                                $generic = array('No', 'Yes');
                                                for($i=0;$i<count($generic);$i++){
                                            ?>
                                                    <option value="<?php echo ($i); ?>" <?php echo (isset($row))?(($row->is_get_sponsored ='y'== 1)?"selected":""):"";?>>
                                                        <?php echo $generic[$i];?>
                                                    </option>
                                            <?php
                                                }
                                            ?> </option> 
</select>
```

Comment: Add the code in question.

Comment: You were not storing value within any of those variable

Comment: before it i had try this. but only print yes.

Comment: @Uchiha : thanks for your clue.

Comment: @Sougata : thanks for your response

Comment: Voting to close as Typo. Wish I could vote to close the Answer as unclear. There is no benefit here for a future reader.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope you need something like this.

```
<?php
$row->is_sponsored_by = 'y';//already stored value
$dropDnArr = array('y' => 'Yes', 'n' => 'No');//Say y & n storing DB And Yes & No is to display
echo "selected value ={$row->is_sponsored_by}<br/>";  ?> 
<label>Get Sponsored <span style="color:red">*</span></label>
<select style="width:100px;" class="form-control" name="sponsor"> <?php
    foreach ($dropDnArr AS $key => $value) {?>
        <option value="<?php echo $key;?>" 
                <?php echo (isset($row)) ? (($row->is_sponsored_by == $key) ? "selected" : "") : "";?> >
            <?php echo $value;?>
        </option> <?php
    } ?>
</select>
```

Comment: thanks for your response and your solution. i've edit a little and it work. Thanks.